# Inline Video Playback In Trigger.io

Tags: ios, html, video, uiwebview, trigger.io

Is there a way to play video without it launching fullscreen? Trigger.IO API does not have an option to set it up apparently, and adding 'webkit-playsinline' inside HTML5 video tag is not enough on iPhone as well, as it needs property 'allowsInlineMediaPlayback' of 'UIWebView' to be set as 'YES'.

I would expect Trigger.IO to have some kind of option to trigger this property on or off...

P.S. It looks like Phone Gap supports it already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily write your own [native module](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html) to change WebView properties in a Trigger.io app. The function would probably look a lot like this:

```
+ (void)enableInlineMediaPlayback:(ForgeTask*)task {
    if (NSClassFromString(@"WKWebView") && [[ForgeApp sharedApp] useWKWebView]) {
        // Handle new WebView 
        WKWebView *webView = (WKWebView*)[[ForgeApp sharedApp] webView];
        WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
        webView.configuration = configuration;
    } else {
        // Handle old WebView
        UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView*)[[ForgeApp sharedApp] webView];
        webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    }
    [task success:nil];
}
```

Additionally, you need to add the `webkit-playsinline` attribute to the video HTML tag.

---

**EDIT:** I've adjusted the code to include relevant code for iOS8 and WKWebView.

Comment: just need to learn now how to do it :] I was expecting that the whole point is to not get into native code and Xcode...

Comment: I guess there are just so many use-cases that it would really blow-up the Trigger.io core to much when adding them all. But I agree with you that this is a pain nonetheless.

Comment: I did it :] worked perfectly, thanks for directing me the right way!

Comment: Glad to hear that! There are many other useful properties that can be changed just as easily ;)

Comment: hey do you know if this code changes now with new ios8 release?

Comment: Yes it actually does. Sorry for the late response. You need to adjust your webview access a bit. Check out the migration guide provided by Trigger.io: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/ios_8_migration_guide.html#4-forgeapp-sharedapp-webview-changes

Comment: Hi Patrick Rudolph, inlinevideoplay is not working with WKWebView for youtube. When I opened the video it goes fullscreen. Any idea about that?